# Exclude subdirectory from host resolution set in /etc/hosts (with dnsmasq, or anything else)

Tags: linux, unix, dnsmasq, hosts, hosts-file

I have a local development tool ([LocalWP](http://localwp.com/)) that sets the path to my local environment by modifying `/etc/hosts`.

For example, if I set my site in Local to `www.foo.com`, it'll append the following to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.foo.com
```

This is fine, but I need to exclude a *subdirectory* (not a subdomain) in this domain, so it resolves to another (the original) IP.

Of course, this isn't possible with `etc/hosts` because it is just a DNS pointer and doesn't resolve anything except the domain. However, I'm wondering if there's another tool I can use to exclude a subdirectory from the current `hosts` file, and point it to a new IP.

I'm wondering if something like dnsmasq can accomplish this, or if there's another tool I could use for some conditional DNS behavior based on the resolution of the path, rather than just the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.

Name resolution is handled by DNS (or `/etc/hosts`, or dnsmasq, or whatever else), but everything after the first `/` is part of the HTTP protocol, and as such is handled by your web browser (on your side) and the web server (on the other side); DNS (or `/etc/hosts`, or dnsmasq, or whatever else) is only used to find the IP address associated with the host name, which will always be the same regardless of the subdirectory you are trying to access; the actual HTTP path will only be used *after* the connection is established.